# Find majority element in an array in java

Tags: java

I am trying to find out the majority Element in an array ad this code is working fine when I am checking with  elements less than size. But it is giving me arrayindexoutofbound exception whenever any element is equal to size of array. Please let me know how to resolve this.

```
public class MajorityElement {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[]={2,2,7,5,2,2,6};
        printMajority(a, 7);
    }

    //1st condition to check if element is in majority.
    public static int findCandidate(int a[], int size){
        int maj_index=0;
        int count =1;
        int i;
        size=a.length;

        for(i=1;i<a.length;i++ ){
            if(a[maj_index]==a[i])
                count++;
            else
                count--;
            if(count==0)
            {
                maj_index=a[i];                      //current element takes max_inex position.
                count =1;
            }

        }

        return a[maj_index];
    }

    public static boolean isMajority(int a[], int size, int cand){
        int i, count =0;

        for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            if(a[i]==cand)
                count++;
        }
        if(count>size/2){
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    private static void printMajority(int a[],int size){
        size=a.length;
        int cand=findCandidate( a, 7);

        if(isMajority(a,size,cand))
            System.out.printf("%d",cand);
        else
            System.out.println("no such element as majority");

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain, with example inputs and outputs, what you want to achieve? I have no idea what "majority element" means, and given that the code is buggy, it's hard to guess what it means by reading the code.

Comment: Maybe `maj_index=a[i];` should be `maj_index=i;`

Comment: Don't write `if (count>size/2) { return true; } else { return false; }`. Just write `return count > size / 2;`

Comment: @JBNizet http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/majority-element/ This is probably a school assignment.

Comment: Just curious: why isn't your iteration in `findCandidate()` beginning at `0`?

Comment: by the way, what means "majority element"??

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `maj_index=a[i];` line. You take the value of one of the cells of the array and assign it to `maj_index` which is subsequently used as an index into the array (see `a[maj_index] == a[i]`). Thus, if the value at that position was larger than the size of the array an out-of-bounds situation will occur.

Here's your code slightly revised. In particular, I got rid of the `maj_index` variable so that the index vs. value mixup cannot happen. I also used a for-each loop `for (int current : a)` instead of the for-loop `for(int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)`. Finally, I eliminated the  the `size` parameter (no need to pass it, it can be inferred from the array itself via `a.length`)

```
public class MajorityElement {

  // 1st condition to check if element is in majority.
  public static int findCandidate(int a[]) {
    int cand = a[0];
    int count = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
      if (cand == a[i])
        count++;
      else
        count--;
      if (count == 0) {
        cand = a[i];
        count = 1;
      }
    }
    return cand;
  }

  public static boolean isMajority(int a[], int cand) {
    int count = 0;

    for (int current : a) {
      if (current == cand)
        count++;
    }
    return count > a.length / 2;
  }

  private static void printMajority(int a[]) {
    int cand = findCandidate(a);
    if (isMajority(a, cand))
      System.out.printf("%d", cand);
    else
      System.out.println("no such element as majority");

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a[] = { 9, 7, 9, 5, 5, 5, 9, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 7 };
    printMajority(a);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your :

```
for(i=1;i<a.length;i++ ){
            if(a[maj_index]==a[i])
                count++;
            else
                count--;
            if(count==0)
            {
                maj_index=a[i];                      //current element takes max_inex position.
                count =1;
            }

        }

        return a[maj_index];
```

here you are getting the value as like :`a[maj_index]` for a test data int `a[]={2,1,8,8,8,8,6};` the elemnt 8 is the major but a[maj_index] is invalid which is causing the issue,

Instead Complete code can be like below:

```
public class TestMajor {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[]={2,1,8,8,8,8,6};
        printMajority(a, 7);
    }

    //1st condition to check if element is in majority.
    public static int findCandidate(int a[], int size){
    int test = a[0];
        int count =1;
        int i;
        size=a.length;

        for(i=1;i<a.length;i++ ){
            if(test ==a[i])
                count++;
            else
                count--;
            if(count==0)
            {
            test =a[i];                      //current element takes max_inex position.
                count =1;
            }

        }

        return test;
    }

    public static boolean isMajority(int a[], int size, int cand){
        int i, count =0;

        for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            if(a[i]==cand)
                count++;
        }
        if(count>size/2){
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    private static void printMajority(int a[],int size){
        size=a.length;
        int cand=findCandidate( a, 7);

        if(isMajority(a,size,cand))
            System.out.printf("%d",cand);
        else
            System.out.println("no such element as majority");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Majority Element in an Array using Java 8 OR Find the element appeared max number of times in an array :

```
public class MajorityElement {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {1,3,4,3,4,3,2,3,3,3,3,3};
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(a).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        Map<Integer, Long> map = list.parallelStream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),Collectors.counting()));
        System.out.println("Map => " + map);
        //{1=1, 2=1, 3=8, 4=2}
        map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getValue))//compare the values and get the maximum value
        .map(Entry::getKey)// get the key appearing maximum number of times
        .ifPresentOrElse(System.out::println,() -> new RuntimeException("no such thing"));

        /*
         * OUTPUT : Map => {1=1, 2=1, 3=8, 4=2} 
         * 3
         */
        System.out.println("...............");

        // A very simple method
        //method 2
        Integer maxAppearedElement = list.parallelStream().max(Comparator.comparing(Integer::valueOf)).get();
        System.out.println(maxAppearedElement);
    }//main

}
```